# want to make attribute filtter {{value}} is dynamic. want to use check box value "true" and false when it is unchecked

Tags: angularjs

Javascript:

```
queryarray.$and = copytwo;

console.log("ma]inquery", copytwo)
console.log("queryarray22222", queryarray)


if (queryarray.length == 0) {
  console.log("$scope.rrrrrrrrrrrrrr", queryarray.length == 0)
  queryarray == true;
  console.log("sssssss", queryarray.length == true)
  console.log("ffffffffs", queryarray.length == false)
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="panel-collapse in" id="filter-group{{$index}}" style="height: auto;">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <ul class="simple-list">
      <li ng-repeat="value in attribute.value track by $index">
        <label class="checkbox" ng-click="filter($event.target)">
          <input type="checkbox"
            ng-model="attributeValue" 
            ng-change="attributeSearch(attribute.visiblename, value, attributeValue)"
            id="{{attribute.visiblename}}"
            ng-true-value= "'{{value}}'"
            ng-false-value="''"
            ng-checked="{{value}}" />
          <a>{{value}}</a>
        </label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would you please elaborate a bit more your question?

Comment: attributes" : [ { "name" : "Brand",value" : "Samsung" }, {"name" : "TV byScreen", "value" : "14 inch"},{"name" : "HD Format","value" : "Full HD"       },{"name" : "Technology", "value" : "LED TV"} its a querry when select a check-box the object is add in the array ,but unselected the check-box want to remove the object from the array . but here object is not  remove  it is add one more object in the array .just like attribute filter.

Comment: how to make a attribute filtter if the key and value both are dynamic,

Comment: how to make a attribute filtter if the key and value both are dynamic. when we checked one value its work, but  unchecked the object is not splice the object in side the array .{$or:[attribute: {visiblenam:Brand,name:LG},...... ]} this is the query whereas we want to add and remove object